# How do I edit a todo in React

Tags: reactjs

my question is that when i click on edit icon and edit my todo update it. Then that edited todo display new todo in todo-list.New todo and old todo(which i had edited) both display in todo-list. how to solve this problem? How to display todo in list...which i had edited? can any one help me out. 
here is my code..
todoApp.JSx

```
editTask:function(todo_id,newValue,todoStartDate,todoEndDate){
        console.log(todo_id,newValue,todoStartDate,todoEndDate);
        axios.post('/edittodos',{
            todo_id:todo_id,
            todo_text:newValue,
            todo_start_at:todoStartDate,
            todo_end_at:todoEndDate
        }).then(function (response){

        }).catch(function (error){



       });
//how to display todo in list after editing todo
            this.setState({
                todos:[
                {
                    todo_text:newValue,
                    todo_start_at:todoStartDate,
                    todo_end_at:todoEndDate
                 },
                ...this.state.todos,
                ]
             });

        },
```

todo.jsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your setState, you are actually adding a todo rather than replacing it

Do it like

```
var todos = [...this.state.todos];
   var index = todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.todo_id == todo_id)
   todos[index].todo_text = newValue
   todos[index].todo_start_at = todoStartDate
   todos[index].todo_end_at=todoEndDate
   this.setState({
                todos
             });
```

Comment: do you know this error after page refresh SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: after login i redirect to todoApp. and my url is like this http://localhost:8080/todoapp/?status=true. If i refresh my page with this url i get error

Comment: How do you redirect, can you add the code, also do you have another question on that

Comment: which issue? syntaxError..!

Comment: no...I am getting another problem. so i am trying to solve them