# ListView not re-rander after update or edite data react native

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native

**Update Post**

## Khatri I think your right so I was change my code But Still I am not understand How to re-rander my list after Update my todo text.

I make a Todo app.Everything is ok. But When i am going to change my todo text it changing on database successfully, But without re-open my app I can not see my update text or todo.
How to re-render after change my text ?

```
        const myFirebaseRef = Firebase.database().ref();
        this.itemsRef = myFirebaseRef.child('items');

        this.state = {
            newTodo: '',
            todoSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2}),
            modalVisible: false,
            editTodoVal: 'Edit Your Todo',
            updateId: '',
            refreshing: false,
        };
        this.items = [];


componentDidMount() {
        this.itemsRef.on('child_added', (dataSnapshot) => {
            this.items.push({id: dataSnapshot.key, text: dataSnapshot.val()});
            this.setState({
                todoSource: this.state.todoSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
            });
        });

        this.itemsRef.on('child_removed', (dataSnapshot) => {
      
            this.items = this.items.filter((x) => x.id !== dataSnapshot.key);
            this.setState({
                todoSource: this.state.todoSource.cloneWithRows(this.items)
            });
        });
        this.itemsRef.on('child_changed', (dataSnapshot) => {
            // what code hare I can make for it ???
        });

    }


addTodo() {
    if (this.state.newTodo !== '') {
        console.log('ADD Todo Successfully');
        this.itemsRef.push({
            todo: this.state.newTodo
        });
        this.setState({
            newTodo: ''
        });
    }
}

updateTodo() {
    if (this.state.editTodoVal !== '') {
        this.itemsRef.child(this.state.updateId)
            .update({
                todo: this.state.editTodoVal
            });
        alert('Success fully update Todo');
        this.setState(this.state);
        this.setState({
            editTodoVal: ''
        });
        this.setModalVisible(false)
    }
}

removeTodo(rowDate) {
    this.itemsRef.child(rowDate.id).remove();
}

 editTodo(rowDate) {
    this.setState({
        editTodoVal: rowDate.text.todo,
        updateId: rowDate.id
    });

    this.setModalVisible(true)
}

            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.todoSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>

renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.appContainerBody}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.todoText}>{rowData.text.todo}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.actionView}>
                    <Text onPress={() => this.removeTodo(rowData)} style={styles.removedText}>
                        <FontAwesome name="trash" size={16}/>
                    </Text>
                    <Text onPress={() => this.editTodo(rowData)} style={styles.editeText}>
                        <FontAwesome name="pencil-square-o" size={16}/>
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't rerender your App beacause, you are mutating the state directly which is a wrong thing to do. You should make use of setState method to update the state which also triggers a rerender after successful state change

```
editTodo(rowDate) {
    this.setState({
         editTodoVal: rowDate.text.todo, 
         updateId:  rowDate.id
    });

    this.setModalVisible(true)
}
```

Comment: #khtri  Thanks for your advice but still I am not get the solution how to re rander after change the value or todo. I allready apply your code

Comment: Ok, how are you rendering the existing todos. You will need to update the array also from where you are rendering

Comment: See this on how to update todo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404200/reactjs-after-editing-todo-how-to-display-todo-in-list/44404387#44404387

Comment: #Khatri Again Thanks . 
Actually I am totally New in react-native . 
I already try 4+ hours and I am not get the point  of your link can and Can you help to say which line or code have to add for it. If you have Time .:)

Comment: You should be doing this in the editTodo function itself.

Comment: I already change editTodo and follow your link but I do not get the point :(

Comment: `this.itemsRef.on('child_changed', (dataSnapshot) => {
            // what code hare I can make for it ???
        });`
Have anything hare to do ??
I really Not understand where I have write the ... right code :(