# Add edit todo function and update state correctly in react todo app

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have the following component which adds a todo to my todo list. The todo's are not displaying in input field but was thinking I can run onclick function if button is clicked then I can edit the existing todo.

Here is what I have started with, I just need some guidance where to go from here. At the moment when I click on the edit todo button it adds another item but not editing the existing one. I have suspicion I am not editing the state as I am supposed to.

My edit todo function:

```
editTodo = (title) => {
    console.log("Edit todo:" + title)
    const editTodo = {
      title:title,
      edited: false
    }
    this.setState({ todos: [
      ...this.state.todos, editTodo 
    ]
  });
  }
```

My edit button next to todo item:

```
<button className="edit-btn" onClick={this.props.editTodo.bind(this, id)}>EDIT</button>
```

My edit todo component

```
class EditTodo extends Component {
  state = {
    edited: false
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.editTodo(this.state.title); 
    this.setState({ title: ''}); 
  }

  onChange = (e) =>
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value  
  }
  );


  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          placeholder="Edit Your Todo"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <button
          type="submit">
          Edit
        </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Update:

I made some changes, implemented a fake backend and reviewed this again and it makes sense to use the same logic as the delete function, how can I change the following to edit my current todo:

Here is my delete todo function

```
deleteTodo = (id) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3004/todos/${id}`)
    .then(res => this.setState({
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos.filter(todo => 
          todo.id !== id 
        )]
    }));
  }
``
```

Comment: You are describing your problem accurately. Right now you are just creating a new todo object and adding it to your array of todos. I think you have two options. Find the todo object you want to edit and change the values or find and delete the old object and push your new todo.

Comment: Yep exactly, so I figured I can use almost the same logic as the add todo component but somehow just add logic to edit, which I need help with :) would adding conditional after the current item with input box to edit the item sound like something that can be done? @BenDubs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404200/how-do-i-edit-a-todo-in-react this is a decent way to do it.

Comment: thank you for this @BenDubs but they are using axios here, i just want to pass it to my state for now before implementing the backend. how would i go about editing current state?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I followed initially was not working. Ref's solved my problem, the final solution posted here: [edit todo list state not passed correctly in react with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088323/edit-todo-list-state-not-passed-correctly-in-react-with-axios/56089492#56089492)